# Setting colors of a submesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I set colors of a submeshes vertices without re-generating it? Mesh class has methods for setting Triangles and Indices of a submesh, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set any vertex attributes for a submesh. You can only assign attributes to the entire mesh, and split it up into submeshes as you please. Consider this "regeneration" if you like; I don't recognize that term.

Comment: Yes, I decided to avoid using submeshes at all in the end.